# Ruby Gem to let users download Word and other files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to allow users to my site to download Word (and other )files.  Is there a gem that's works with Rails 3.1 which allows this, or another straightforward way to do it?

The files are regular text files, unrelated to the code that makes the actual app. For example, the files might contain stories and poems etc

Comment: If you just want to download existing files, you don't need a gem at all. Are you asking how to create Word files programmatically?

Comment: The files that will be downloaded already exist off the site. I have pdf and word copies of them. They are text files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a file exists in the `public/` directory, all you have to do is create a link to the file

---

E.g., If you have `public/shared/my_file.doc`, you can create a link using:

```
<%= link_to 'My File', '/shared/my_file.doc' %>
```

Comment: and that creates a download link? it's that simple?

Comment: To make this more clear, if your rails site runs at http://localhost:3000 and you have a file public/mydoc.doc, then visiting http://localhost:3000/mydoc.doc will download the file.

Comment: well that's pretty easy, thanks. (I guess you can see i'm a noob)